# Treasure Map Drawing Bot

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You're organizing a treasure hunt for your friends. To conduct things more easily, you want to draw a map of all locations where you hid the precious objects.

### Input

Any form of input denoting a list of points consisting of (nonnegative) x- and y-coordinate, `0 0` being the upper left corner is permitted (Note: You may also use 1-based indexing in your answer, please comment on that if you do). Example:

```
1 2
3 0
0 1
```

### Challenge

Your function or program should be able to construct a map denoting every given location with an `x` where the mark is found in row y + 1 and column x + 1 in the output. Unmarked locations are represented with a  . The map also consists of a frame where the corners are `+`s, the vertical lines are `|`s and the horizontal lines are `-`s. Your solution should output the smallest possible frame. Map for the input example given above:

```
+----+
|   x|
|x   |
| x  |
+----+
```

### Possible Test Cases

---

```
"0 0"
=>
+-+
|x|
+-+
```

---

```
"0 10
 5 5
 10 0"
=>
+-----------+
|          x|
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|     x     |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|x          |
+-----------+
```

---

```
""
=>
++
++
```

---

```
"0 0
 0 2
 2 0"
=>
+---+
|x x|
|   |
|x  |
+---+
```

---

Of course, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), meaning that the solution with the lowest byte count wins! Explanations of your solution are encouraged.

Comment: Not really, but i couldn't really think about another input format. But I'm willing to change that if it benefits the challenge.

Comment: Can there be non square maps?

Comment: Of course, the example used in the explanation uses a nonsquare map. It all depends on the input coordinates

Comment: @racer290 I'd suggest just saying something like `the input is a list of locations (e.g. nested list, list of tuples, space & newline separated, separate inputs, ect.)`

Comment: Can the output be a 2d array of characters?

Comment: Can I submit a function taking the x- and y-coordinates as two separate arguments?

Comment: Should the frame be as small as possible?

Comment: @ovs It should be a string consisting of the printable ascii characters as stated above.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, I'll add that to the challenge description, thank you.

Comment: @BMO Yes, the challenge permits any form of input denoting the coordinates you like.

Comment: Testcase: `10 10`. Should the output be the same as `0 0`?  Smallest possible frame.

Comment: @edc Okay, well you can interpret it that way, but what i mean here is no overhead in the positive x or y direction.

Comment: "This wouldn't be so bad in 05AB1E" [10... minutes... later] "What the [!@$*...](https://tio.run/##AVkApv9vc2FiaWX//09aUcOPPmBgVUYnfE5WWEZZTuKAmsK5cy7DpeKAniB4w6h9J3zCtkp9WCctw5cnKy7DuMK2wqtExaBK//9bWzAsMF0sWzUsNV0sWzQsMTBdXQ)"

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
0<@|:' x'{~((i.@]e.#.~)1+>./) ::#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxCoAwEAXR3lN8sIjism4Um0UlF7GSiNrYCkquHlMo2A2P2WNcBob07laD01yhKDZ2k@ecQ2mrkesSqrlGP68HFgisEDp0pKkg2esWDaGFJE7Lp8Z8RfqbSVvY@AA)

```
                       1+>./          maximum for each coordinate + 1
             i.@]                     make an array with these dimensions filled with 0..x*y
                                      /* if the input is empty, 
                                         1+>./ is negative infinity
                                         and i.@] throws an error  */
                   #.~                mixed base conversion of input
                 e.                   replace the elements of i.@]
                                        with 1 if it's present in the
                                        converted input, 0 otherwise
           (                ) ::      if there's an error do the other thing instead
                                #:    "to binary", for empty input this returns a 0x0 matrix
0<@|:' x'{~                           index into character string, transpose and put in a box
```

Comment: I guess that output formatting is better than the one I proposed ;)

Comment: Why is the `::empty` so verbose? What's it do? Why can't it be simplified to 1 byte or so? (I have no knowledge of J)

Comment: I ran it on TIO without ::empty and it seemed to work(dont know J either)

Comment: Actually ::empty seems to handle the “” input case

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I don’t know a shorter way to output a truly empty box, they are 1 row high by default.

Comment: Turns out it can be avoided if the input is a 0×2 nothing.
[6 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##TY1dCoJAFIXfXcWBHiwabneUXoYSaQHtwAepMQ38wRnIKNxGC2ph0wgZHbhw@fg45@pcsSfwLn2qEEP4GLNlRWmmaUHjihOS64Q2Tp/KFgUYkgW22ArlP3Dw5RKRQAz22CvBjH1lKPwBxwMhgq47e0ff3gxsnzema40@z3JF7JUpk8zvV4Q6t301CJi81rBl1Vx@1UL9zQsVQ7oP)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 150 bytes

Takes input as a list of 1-indexed coordinates in `[x,y]` format. Returns a string.

```javascript
a=>(g=w=>y<h?' |-+x'[4*a.some(a=>a+''==[x,y])|2*(-~y%h<2)|++x%w<2]+[`
`[x=x<w?x:+!++y]]+g(w):'')((M=i=>Math.max(2,...a.map(a=>a[i]+2)))(x=y=0),h=M(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzBisIwFEX3foWzkLznS8M0igvpq1/QLwgBg1PbDq2RqdgEir9e6zCrATeHy72H@@3urj/9NNdbcvFf5XTmyXEOFQ@cx6w@iOWYUBBmu3aq910J8@pICGYTZLQ46jUkj7iqM40jUVgNmbZkjoujCRyy4RD29EEUraUKBtwLgQAFN5wX7larzgXQUinl5nj9PTeNJY2IEDjyJ8qaC0gRp5O/9L4tVesrOIOxiIt/lUllat/1cuZm5ua985J2cvdS/56mJw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>127</s> 123 bytes

This defines the operator `(!)` which takes a list of *x*-coordinates and a list of the corresponding *y*-coordinates:

```hs
x!y|l<-'+':('-'<$m x)++"+"=unlines$l:['|':[last$' ':['x'|(i,j)`elem`zip x y]|i<-m x]++"|"|j<-m y]++[l];m x=[1..maximum$0:x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xboMwEIZ3nuJPhGQQcVSWDhSydO3WkSLFCk7q1AZkG9WueHd6ZIiXu/t8n@7/Fu5Har2uYRcXXXNWsCpjnNWpQciLYl/sm3nQapAu1VXLFla1WjifMlDHAlsydbjnZ6mlOf@pCQGxW1TNSe9IX/bLfRsiDa3u3gg3bXk8GhGUmU36UoVuNUINaNCPCRCiQ81hxAQrRf9Bl3HEIwDq9ISb9O/j4OXgHW1r6REcuVfnH9@kE95e3LAb@icmPs3@01tkpOxoIU8SznEZB@ftfPHw86QlrnY0cJO4SDg5CSu87KHo5E1alzxDNci@2nCIHT8h2yjC4VFinlPi39H2bi1RlskrXpOSun8)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

The helper function `m` expects a list and returns indices (1-based) up to the maximum, if the list is empty it returns `[]`:

```hs
m x | null x    = []
    | otherwise = [1 .. maximum x]
```

The actual operator `(!)` is just a list-comprehension, traversing all the coordinates and choosing a  or `x` character, which gets joined with newlines:

```hs
x ! y
  -- construct the top and bottom line
  | l <- "+" ++ replicate (maximum (0:x)) '-' ++ "+"
  -- join the list-comprehension with new-lines
  = unlines $ 
  -- prepend the top line
      [l]
  -- the actual map:
    -- begin the line with | and add the correct chars for each coordinate
      ++ [ "|" ++ [ if (i,j) `elem` zip x y then 'x' else ' '
    -- "loop" over all x-coordinates
                 | i <- m x
                 ]
    -- end the line with a |
           ++ "|"
    -- "loop" over all y-coordinates
         | j <- m y
         ]
  -- append the bottom line
      ++ [l]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ø╶｛X；┤╋｝ｌ|＊ｅＬ┤-×+ｅ：└∔∔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyNTc2JXVGRjVCWCV1RkYxQiV1MjUyNCV1MjU0QiV1RkY1RCV1RkY0QyU3QyV1RkYwQSV1RkY0NSV1RkYyQyV1MjUyNC0lRDcrJXVGRjQ1JXVGRjFBJXUyNTE0JXUyMjE0JXUyMjE0,i=JTVCJTVCMiUyQzIlNUQlMkMlNUIyJTJDMyU1RCUyQyU1QjMlMkMyJTVEJTJDJTVCMTAlMkMxMCU1RCU1RA__,v=2)

Takes 1-indexed inputs.

Finally decided to fix a bug that's been annoying me for ages and golfed this down to [21 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyNTc2JXVGRjVCJXUyNTI0WCV1MjU0QiV1RkY1RCV1RkY0QyU3QyV1RkYwQSV1RkY0NSV1RkYyQyV1MjUyNC0lRDcrJXVGRjQ1JXVGRjFBJXUyNTE0JXUyMjE0JXUyMjE0,i=JTVCJTVCMiUyQzIlNUQlMkMlNUIyJTJDMyU1RCUyQyU1QjMlMkMyJTVEJTJDJTVCMTAlMkMxMCU1RCU1RA__,v=2).

Explanation (half-ASCII-fied for monospace):

```
ø╶{X;┤╋}l|*eL┤-×+e:└++  full program, implicitly outputting ToS at the end
ø                       push an empty Canvas - the map
 ╶{    }                for each array in the input array
   X                      push "X"
    ;┤                    and push the two coordinates separately on the stack
      ╋                   and overlap the "X" there in the map
        l               get the vertical length of the map
         |*             repeat "|" vertically that many times
           e            encase the map in two of those vertical bars
            L           get the horizontal length of the map
             ┤          subtract 2 (leave place for the "+"es)
              -×        repeat "-" that many times
                +e      encase that line in "+"es
                  :└    push a copy of that below the map
                    ++  and join the 3 items vertically
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>151</s> <s>140</s> 138 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Jo King.

Input is 1-indexed.

```python
m=input()
w,h=map(max,zip((0,0),*m))
b=['+'+'-'*w+'+']
M=b+['|'+' '*w+'|']*h+b
for x,y in m:M[y]=M[y][:x]+'x'+M[y][x+1:]
print'\n'.join(M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU6xbsMgEN35ipMXwNAqdqoMlhiTzerSjTLYLpVpY4wQkXGVf3cNVaOT7r27997p3BrG2dbbMH9o4Yui2CZhrLsFQtHCRzF1jkxd5D/GEXLgB8rLiVLUC4nZXk@4XBIq1IqeSXzfOeTdHatyZD36nD1EvoKxMDWtXJVITTZRMRwxy0NkVaOQ88YG/G7x89dsLGnptr@D0DKaq4Y3f9MNAgh@TQCgox4gfZ2nnEVpO2gX4Px6OXs/@z9r73X3vUlSczhSTl44VDtUHGqqkEykepCknDickuFfeJhyKJ04ZuUX)

Comment: I suspect that you're using 1-based indexing, please leave a note on that in your answer as stated in the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
≔Ｅ²⁺²⌈Ｅθ§λιηＢ⊟⮌η⊟ηＦθ«Ｊ⊟⮌ι⊟ιx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Bi8IwEIXPya8Yepqw8aDubU96U1SKeCs9hO7YBtKkNqkUxN8eE8GDc/mG9x4zr@nU2DhlYtRXwJMLeCDbhg5vQgg4UxOUbQ3hSkLxU4g/TsYTPDjbeK9bi0c1ZK80k888qln3U/@WbxI2YWf/aUYjQYs8Erp0g23djKUb8Ex3Gj1hl50spCXZVzdCKpDfsP3UDxf3ldaftH6nWTlqG7CYcz325M8Yq4pXqc26lrz6lbDMXEpYJdZ1XNzNCw) Link is to verbose version of code. 1-indexed. Explanation:

```
¿¬ＬθＵＲ²+«
```

Special-case empty input by drawing a 2x2 rectangle of `+`s.

```
≔Ｅ²⁺²⌈Ｅθ§λιη
```

Transpose the input, take the maximum of each column (now row) and add 2 to get the box size in Charcoal co-ordinates.

```
Ｂ⊟⮌η⊟η
```

Draw the box.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over each co-ordinate.

```
Ｊ⊟⮌ι⊟ι
```

Jump to its position.

```
x
```

Mark with a cross.

Comment: Seems to fail for empty input: https://tio.run/##VYq7CsIwGIXn5ilCpz8QF9dOdVMoBHErHUKNJpBbk6YExGePjeDgWc7tmyUPs@O6lD5G9bQwcA9HiplOsfrAszLJfOeF4n4927vIoClWpIpiSTp0chmY83AVmwhRgKxHHfbQoYcLGBaCX6i5JONv7o9VP1ZVtmFB2RXa3O7lXco4omkqh01/AA

Comment: @wastl Thanks, I've come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╩╠ee%╙æM■↓^⌐╧ΩΓ¡c¥èf¢○ [
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cacc656525d3914dfe195ea9cfeae2ad639d8a669b09205b&i=[[0,10],[5,5],[10,0]]%0A[]%0A[[0,0],[0,2],[2,0]]&a=1&m=2)

Takes 0-based indices as array of `[y, x]` pairs.

Explanation:

```
zs'X&|<cM%'-*'+|S]s{'||Smn++m Unpacked program, implicit input
zs                            Tuck empty array under input
  'X                          Push "X"
    &                         Assign element at all indices (create map)
                                As the indexing arrays are an array of arrays, treat them as a path to navigate a multidimensional array.
                                Extend array if needed.
     |<                       Left-align all to the length of the longest.
       cM%                    Copy, transpose, length (width)
          '-*                 Repeat "-"
             '+|S             Surround with "+"
                 ]s           Make a singleton and tuck it below the map
                   {    m     Map:
                    '||S        Surround with "|"
                         n++  Surround with the above/below border (built above)
                            m Map:
                                Implicit output
```

Comment: Nicely done.  You can get a little more mileage out of the `|S` surround instruction, and a trailing shorthand map. (`m`)  Surround takes `a` and `b` from the stack and produces `b+a+b`.  And you can use `m` instead of the final `|J` to iterate over the rows and produce output.  [For example](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83d28cf9347f18507fe593a875f38bf4d7b47136a26a8996f495bf&i=[[0,10],[5,5],[10,0]]%0A[]%0A[[0,0],[0,2],[2,0]]&a=1&m=2)

Comment: One more thing: you can replace `z]n+H%` with `cM%`.  This is the piece that gets the map width, but has a special case for empty maps.  If you transpose the map before measuring it, the special case goes away.

Comment: @recursive I had been looking for something like surround, but I searched for the wrong keywords

Comment: What would you naturally call that operation?  I may add it to the docs so the next person can find it.

Comment: @recursive I don't remember what it was, and I would naturally call it surround now

Comment: @recursive After reading my old explanation, it turns out I called it "wrap a in b"

Comment: That makes sense.  It will be in the 1.1.2 (next release) docs for easy ctrl+F.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>133 125</s> 122 bytes

```r
function(m)cat(z<-c("+",rep("-",u<-max(m[,1])),"+","
"),rbind("|",`[<-`(matrix(" ",u,max(m[,2])),m,"x"),"|","
"),z,sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCoMwEEX3fkWYbiY4KcbiptgvkYJpjK2LqGgEkf67TeyD0sLMYu6Zc4e1ZrlY66nVrulatFwrh0suNEIMNJgeQQBNubBqRluQPHNOAUEEnIZL01YId6CyyEWJVrmhmRGYV@hlpMGwBLP/D5@buNBo@hMAX3dS@A4zm@rIVFU17ZXFkrmOuZthzoyOaTWacR/V73aNkg6UUOpX8tgfnH/ThJKQyt80I5mEyZ7839oa0w9dHw)

1-indexed. Takes a matrix as argument. Saved 8 bytes thanks to digEmAll, 3 thanks to Giuseppe!
Explanation (earlier version of code):

```r
function(m){                           #x and y are the 1st and 2nd col of m
s=matrix(32,u<-max(m[,1]),max(m[,2]))  #s (treasure map) has dim max(x), max(y) 
s[m]=120                               #place the X's on the map
cat(                                   #print:
    z<-c("+",rep("-",u),"+","\n"),     #the top line
    intToUtf8(rbind(124,s,124,13)),    #the map
    z,                                 #the bottom line.
    sep="")
}
```

Comment: If you use normal chars instead of utf8 codes you save 8 characters : https://tio.run/##ZU7NDoIwDL7zFEu9tKEzDONF4UkMhzmGchgYNhKC@uwIaozRpG36/TXtpkpkcqr6xoS6bdDR1edOh64eEARwn0mnB3QHVgXxe00Lor0/uCKHAfZGBxwzaRBi4M5eEOScI14gREDcHeumRLgBe17mkxzZ20sOQNF9Wik5O@xgy53QZVk3JxErEVoRzlYE64Mw2lu/jip8v2ZQ8YYTTudWFM@A6FtNOFlY9ctuWSVLbV/6f@p5Mf2o0wM

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCoMwEEX3fkWYbiY4KcbiptgvkYJpjK2LqGgEkf67TeyD0sLMYu6Zc4e1ZrlY66nVrulatFwrh0suNEIMNJgeQQBNubBqRluQPHNOAUEEnIZL01YId6CyyEWJVrmhmRGYV@hlpMGwBLP/D5@buNBo@hMAX3dS@A4zm@rIVFU17ZXFkrmOuZthzoyOaTWacR/V73aNkg6UUOpX8tgfnH/ThJKQyt80I5mEyZ7839oa0w9dHw) by using `[<-` directly to remove the braces.

Comment: @Giuseppe indeed! I knew there had to be a way.

Answer (score 1):

coords taken of the format [y,x]

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>191</strike> 184 bytes

```javascript
c=f=a=>{a.map(([y,x])=>(c[M<++y?M=y:y]=c[y]||[])[m<++x?m=x:x]="x",M=m=0)
m++
M++
s=""
for(i=0;i<=M;s+=`
`,i++)for(j=0;j<=m;j++)s+=(c[i]||0)[j]||(j%m?i%M?" ":"-":i%M?"|":"+") 
return s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BasMwEEX3OoURBCSkBCWQje2JT6ATCEGEaheJyA52UiTqnt2dtLvSxfz5vPkzE92HW/wc7o/9OL312wCbhwEcXD7dIbk7Y6bIbDlcmDe6FaJ0GkpdLHhT7Loay01CnLsEuc4WaKZSQwLFSRKCaKwFKCXDNLMAqgkt6GYRcCVXGYTgLx6RxxZSExHgDF8FvK24idhY3KUu7HRHK1rTPa1//IpeUF6RuX8857FavjY/jct06w@36Z0NzBglj8pKc5Zn1KOSylrOyZ/UP8i8ohL1hHr6Xdu@AQ)

Comment: I think you accidentally swapped the x- and y-coordinates somewhere..

Comment: @racer290 could you be more specific?

Comment: Trying your solution, I found that changing the x coordinate in the test cases led to a change in the vertical direction of the coordinate. I guess the bug is in the first row (`a.map(([y,x])`)

Comment: but x is the right paramter as can be seen by the test cases

Comment: So in your solution you take the y coordinate first? I think it'd be better to leave a note on that in your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 180 bytes

```js
F = 

s=>s.map(([x,y])=>(t[y]=t[Y<y?Y=y:y]||[])[X<x?X=x:x]='x',t=[X=Y=0])&&[...t,0].map((_,y)=>[...Array(X+2)].map((_,x)=>[(t[y]||0)[x]||' ',...'-|+'][!(y%~Y)+2*!(x%~X)]).join``).join`
`


console.log(F([[1,11],[6,6],[11,1]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>246</strike> 234 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for the suggestion.

Zero-indexed. The function takes a list of co-ordinates and buffer, finds the maximum x and y values, fills the buffer with spaces, generates the frame, and then plots the 'x's.

```c
f(int*a,char*c){int*b=a,x,y=x=-1,i=0;for(;~*b;*++b>y?y=*b:0,++b)*b>x?x=*b:0;for(x+=4,y+=3,memset(c,32,x*y);++i<x;c[i]=c[y*x-i]=45);for(i=0;i<y;c[x*++i-1]=10*(i<=y))c[x*i]=c[x*i+x-2]=i&&y/i?124:43;for(b=a;~*b;b+=2)c[*b+1-~b[1]*x]='x';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHdbpswGL3nKdxObf1HhyFZpxonV9vtHgBxYRxIjRKogFb2qvTV2WeStdosYXzO8fH3HdvEe2PmL7Yzh5ddjfJx2tn@/mkT/UMdbPU/N9huD9zcYNtNVHPzpAdqyFtAldLcca@cigW3KpFNP2D5TitJGas2fusVrR4TDoDQauO2bsHLNsfUinumMn6sj2M9YcOzlDvqiWTM5k6awpbKFJ66GBarNVlsoYrNPagOathYlEokFNtceUICuZjgx1yclsre3vqvdivS1eMqWw6AnpcOK6ZSMNCKifi9KkRJXanu3J08zRANHbXtQmKkh71ZQiNKYf1K0FuEUFDgMixvJaBFHossffj2vZRR0BscjBtx3g6E0lNvA/kKtYg8kw3GWh314dAbjC1NmSB0tL/rfrltAuNiRyj03kL4NodMo9Fdg69vduhmd801a2l6nuGAK/Xj10/ZMnYpgpAuQCnhjf4S0BwfP@Tnl2nEn7AZ6hrrCzxF4TvNIkFJtEbrKEEimbM/)

Comment: fix bug in bottom row [235 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVHdbpswGL3nKbxOTf3HhCHZphonV@1tHwBxYRxIP5TABLSyV6WvTo2Tbtos2fI5x@f7s4kPxsxfoTPHl32N8nHaQ//teRv9Qx2h@p8boDt4bm4wdBPV3DzrgRrytqBKaW65U1bFgoNKZNMPWL7TSlLGqq3bOUWr@4R7QGi1tTsbcHhmmVpzx1TGT/VprCdseJZySx2RjEFupSmgVKZw1Mb@st6QYAPlJHjNUmA2FqUSCcWQu1gQEtjFcxHTUkEc5261gp1I1/frLETwRYcSK6ZSb6EVE/F7VYiS2lLd2Tt5nn1v6KShW1pGejiY0DWi1N9fCXqLEFoUPw3grfQoyGORpT@@/yxltOgNXoxbcXnuCaWnHhby1eci8kI2GGt10sdjbzAGmjJB6Ai/6z6Mm/h1tSO01N76Gbc5rFaj0V2Db2736HZ/wzVraXo5fYAv6uHpUbaMXZMgpAuvlP6TPglfHB//yL9ephH/hc1Q11hf4Tla9nkWCUqiDdpECRLJnH0A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>238</s> <s>223</s> <s>220</s> 219 bytes

```java
c->{var r="";int w=0,h=0,x,y;for(var l:c){w=(x=l.get(0))>w?x:w;h=(y=l.get(1))>h?y:h;}for(w++,h-=x=-1;x++<w;r+="\n")for(y=-1;y++<h;)r+=x%w+y%h<1?"+":x%w<1?"-":y%h<1?"|":(c+r).contains("["+x+", "+y+"]")?"x":" ";return r;}
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

1-indexed coordinates.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##zVLBauMwED1vvmIYKEhINnVSSrGihD0utL3sse1BVdzYWVcpshJbeP3tWSkN7NJDkz1k2YNA82beaOY9rdRWJavFj52uVdPAnapMPwKojCvsi9IF3McQ4LuzlVmCJqtASDeuqtPbqnHTD@G3wFsWdjYDTUUgDuE0TrlKwz0YudPJrN8qC1YiivAItPKSl@F03IuXtSUxWeea9q0knazTZeHIJaWzdt7lrSgl8QcwC2A593kphshrGeNlIjuZZKJjbNoKyyQ@GqQx6yPsA1wKGvDuomX@opxmc2SYhyjeEswP2E/MiWaWpnptXBCkIfiArGPIAZln@IR0jh3mCChs4TbWgBXDLu77tnmuw66HlbfragGvoQN5l@/hCRQ96OkbV7ym641L30LK1YaYVBNTtPBb0q/WKh91JZTu5fx7Xt@PvqjFgnxINqlq9gVjPomtP6254tnRmoyPQ80wnGvObD/DWfsfX/KaXx8X4h9MeoIbx12dnHnO8bl/xEmW/Rd2TE6w45S/dcNv/thlGA27Xw)

**Explanation:**

```java
c->{                      // Method with 2D Lists as parameter and String return-type
  var r="";               //  Result-String, starting empty
  int w=0,h=0,            //  Width and height, starting at 0
      x,y;                //  Temp x,y coordinates
  for(var l:c){           //  Loop over the Inner Lists containing the coordinates
    w=(x=l.get(0))>w?x:w; //   Determine width based on max x-coordinate
    h=(y=l.get(1))>h?y:h;}//   Determine height based on max y-coordinate
  for(w++,h-=             //  Increase both the width and height by 1
      x=-1;x++<w;         //  Loop `x` in the range [0, width]:
      r+="\n")            //    After every iteration: append a new-line to the result
    for(y=-1;y++<h;)      //   Inner loop `y` in the range [0, height]:
      r+=                 //    Append the following character to the result-String:
         x%w+y%h<1?       //    If it's one of the corners:
          "+"             //     Append "+"
         :x%w<1?          //    Else-if it's the top or bottom row:
          "-"             //     Append "-"
         :y%h<1?          //    Else-if it's the right or left column:
          "|"             //     Append "|"
         :(c+r).contains("["+x+", "+y+"]")? 
                          //    Else-if the current `x,y` is part of the input-coordinates:
          "x"             //     Append "x"
         :                //    Else:
          " ";            //     Append " "
  return r;}              //  Return the result-String
```

Comment: rwhxy; lcwxlgetw? xw; hylgeth? yh; forwhxxwr. foryyhrxwyh? xwyhcxy? xr.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn What are you naming all the variables and `get`/`for` for? :S XD

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
ζεZ}>`UX'-×'+.ø©,F'|NVXF¹YN‚.å„ xè}'|J,}®,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3LZzW6Nq7RJCI9R1D09X19Y7vOPQSh039Rq/sAi3Qzsj/R41zNI7vPRRwzyFisMratVrvHRqD63T@f8/OtpAxyBWJ9pUxxRIGhroGIJ4hoY6ZkDKTMcIxDMx0DEyiY0FAA)

---

```
 ζεZ}>`                                     # Push the max of X and Y to the stack +1.
       UX                                   # Store the max X.
         '-×'+.ø©,                          # Print the top border.
                  F                     }   # From 0 to Y...
                   '|                       # Push left border.
                     NV                     # Store current Y in Y.
                       XF          }        # From 0 to X...
                         ¹                  # Push input.
                          YN‚               # Group current X and Y.
                             .å             # Exists in original input ? 1 : 0
                               „ xè         # Exists ? 'X' : ' '
                                    '|J,    # Right border, join, print.
                                         ®, # Print bottom border.
```

X and Y may be reversed, didn't know if that mattered at all.

---

<s>I think I have this in less bytes, but we'll see...</s> ***Nope.***

```
ζεZ}>`D'-×'+.øUð×'|.øs.D)X.ø©svy>`s®sUXès'xsǝXǝ}
```

Comment: It's not much, but you can save 1 byte by changing the first `F` to `Lv`, remove `NV` and change `Y` to `y`. [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3LZzW6Nq7RJCI9R1D09X19Y7vOPQSh2fMvWaCLdDOyv9HjXM0ju89FHDPIWKwytq1Wu8dGoPrdP5/z862kDHIFYn2lTHFEgaGugYgniGhjpmQMpMxwjEMzHQMTKJjQUA)

Comment: As mentioned by [_@Emigna_ in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47260967#47260967), `εZ}` can be `€à`.

Comment: Hate editing this on mobile will wait until  near pc.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `Ýv` not `Lv`, but still a good edit :).

Comment: Ah, you're right. `Ýv` instead of `Lv`. My bad.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen pretty smart way to get around `vvy`, I didn't think about how a double-nested v-loop would work until hitting it on this problem.

Comment: Yeah, and in the Elixir rewrite it's even worse, since the map and other loops will have their own `y` as well now, instead of just the `v`-loop. Caused me some confusion and rethinking for a recent answer of mine. PS: You still have to update your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>229</s> <s>220</s> 216 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

Zero-indexed. Takes coordinates as list of numbers, where even numbers are X and odd numbers are Y.

```c
X,Y,i,j,k,x,z;f(l,n)int*l;{for(X=Y=0,i=n*=2;i--;X=fmax(l[i],X))Y=fmax(l[i--],Y);n&&X++-Y++;for(--i;i++<Y;puts(""))for(j=-1;j<=X;z=i<0|i==Y,putchar(j++<0|j>X?z?43:'|':x?z?45:32:'x'))for(x=k=n;k--;)x*=l[k--]-i|l[k]-j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LboMwEDyHr0A5BAy2xCsXlm1@wxbigFBJDIZWhUqIx6@XGqImSqWxtDOembULdi2KdeVUUEkrWtOBjlDairZEtr2jYCo/vmyOAj0qsXUwAMkYcCybfLBVKjPKCREPylhGBYH2dOKuy4TrwpZnTIJ03UTA53ff2ccjIZtcIfOhSpDDiDLxZokoqHYUt1xfar83V2/8Ml6iMLZmKx628RyHQWwN1r1iwBpbqPWTyOCgSvWUMTnrIWMVLKv@hNnksrWJMRmHjfXvXe@nmYnm5FHTW@ApBw/Z1@e8w/9vCp/ZHcGOF0t0t2yScSjtfaNuIvDHdCB8svCFRbpMs2X9KUqVX7uVqeYX)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cheers!

Comment: Suggest `for(n&&X++-Y++;i<=Y;i+=puts(""))` instead of `n&&X++-Y++;for(--i;i++<Y;puts(""))`